# Как сделать каждое слово в кириллической строке с заглавной буквы?

Tags: ruby

Чтобы, например `мама мыла раму` стало `Мама Мыла Раму`, а `санкт-петербург` стал `Санкт-Петербург`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с **Ruby 2.4.0** можно так:

```
'санкт-петербург'.gsub(/\b./, &:upcase)
```

В более ранних версиях — с использованием гема [Unicode](https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode):

```
'санкт-петербург'.gsub(/[А-я]+/) { |word| Unicode::capitalize(word) }
```

В **Rails** (или с использованием гема **active_support**) можно так:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'

'санкт-петербург'.mb_chars.titleize.to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

С кириллицей Ruby плохо умеет работать. Настолько, что в Rails порой проще делать это на уровне БД, чем делать преобразования калибром вроде вашего.

В случаях, когда это надо делать именно в Ruby, ваше решение побить очень трудно — нужно использовать или уже упомянутый **гем Unicode** или надстройки над ним. Поэтому ваше решение, наверное, лучшее.

У **ActiveSupport** (части **Rails**, которую в теории можно использовать отдельно) есть метод `mb_chars`, делающий синтаксис чуть более привычным с помощью прокси-класса (или декоратора). Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
'санкт-петербург'.gsub(/[А-я]+/) { |word| word.mb_chars.capitalize }
```

Под капотом у этого всё тот же **гем Unicode** (см. `ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars`), а **ActiveSupport** часто критикуют за обилие *monkeypatch*'ей. Хотя вы можете затянуть только этот метод с помощью:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'
```

Comment: В **Rails** можно, наверное, так: `'санкт-петербург'.mb_chars.titleize.to_s`

Comment: @installero а, про этот хелпер я забыл. Он оттуда же, небось. Вы этот вариант проверили?

Comment: `[2] pry(main)> 'санкт-петербург'.mb_chars.titleize.to_s
=> "Санкт-Петербург"`

Comment: @installero браво, я неправ :D Пишите второй ответ Х)

Answer (score 1):

Если не рассматривать кириллицу, то вот так:

```
s.gsub(/\b./, &:upcase)
```

Comment: А если рассматривать?

Comment: Тогда это вопрос, который следует задать отдельно.

Comment: Поправил заголовок

Comment: Исправлять заголовок через два дня -- не тру.