# Проблема преобразования кириллицы в Ruby

Tags: кодировка, ruby

Проблема в том, что у меня Ruby отказывается использовать преобразование Кириллицы через upcase и downcase.

Пишет ошибку:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError occured.
"\xD1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Пример кода который я использую:

```
require 'unicode'
a = "Андрей"
puts a.Unicode::upcase
puts a.Unicode::downcase
puts a.Unicode::swapcase
puts a.Unicode::capitalize
```

Как я понял, эта ошибка возникает из-за `require`

Версия Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Версия Ruby какая? Случаем не 1.9?
Прикрепите, пожалуйста, полный трейс.

Comment: Что такое трейс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как никто не смог предложить хотя бы самый колхозный вариант решения этой задачи. И так как версия Ruby 1.9.2, в коде поддерживается UTF-8, а также преобразование кириллицы не работает со строками изначально, придётся идти на хитрость писать дополнительные функции (или костыли, кому как удобнее) в класс строки, чтобы можно было также обрабатывать кириллицу.

Допустим взять и сделать 2 переменные - строки, в которых будет расписан кириллический алфавит, далее сделать все необходимые для преобразования функции: капс, нижний регистр, с большой буквы. И обрабатывать эти строки посимвольно:

```
class String
    BIG_RUS   = "АБВГДЕËЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
    SMALL_RUS = "абвгдеëжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"

    # Кириллический upcase
    def rus_upcase
        result = ""
        self.each_char do |c|
            if SMALL_RUS.include?(c)
                result += BIG_RUS[SMALL_RUS.index(c)]
            elsif BIG_RUS.include?(c)
                result += c
            else
                result += c.upcase
            end
        end
        return result
    end

    #Кириллический downcase
    def rus_downcase
        result = ""
        self.each_char do |c|
            if BIG_RUS.include?(c)
                result +=  SMALL_RUS[BIG_RUS.index(c)]
            elsif SMALL_RUS.include?(c)
                result += c
            else
                result += c.downcase
            end
        end
        return result
    end

    #Кириллический capitalize
    def rus_capitalize
        result = self[0].rus_upcase + self[1..-1].rus_downcase 
        return result 
    end
end
p "Привет Hello".rus_upcase     #=> "ПРИВЕТ HELLO"
p "ПрИвет HelLo".rus_downcase   #=> "привет hello"
p "ПРИВЕТ HelLo".rus_capitalize #=> "Привет hello"
```

Я понимаю свой косяк, я не упомянул, что это мне нужно было для RPG Maker и встроенного в него RGSS3 (Ruby Game Scripting System v3 | Ruby 1.9.2). Там же отключена функция require, отчего там вызывало ошибку, вместо внедрения дополнительного функционала.

Для кого-то это решение может оказаться плохим, но это как минимум работает так, как необходимо это было изначально.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема известная, на самом деле окончательно на уровне Ruby она будет решена после выхода релиза Ruby 2.4, в котором можно будет использовать полный Unicode-маппинг из коробки, тогда вам не потребуется никаких дополнительных библиотек и следующий код будет работать корректно

```
a = "Андрей"
a.downcase
```

Comment: Прикол в том что я использую эти методы без библиотек и у меня не трогает слово на кириллице. 
То есть. При всех 4-х перечисленных методах у меня слово, например "Андрей", не изменится.На всех 4 строках выдаст одинаковые данные.

Answer (score 1):

...а пока Ruby 2.4 не вышел, проблему можно решить при помощи обёртки строки, возвращаемой `String#mb_chars` в [`activesupport`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) (из состава Rails, но может использоваться отдельно):

```
# высокоточный require загрузит не весь гем, а только нужный кусочек
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'

'Андрей'.mb_chars.upcase.to_s # => 'АНДРЕЙ'
```

Явный `.to_s` нужен, потому что `mb_chars` и операции на нём возвращают объект-обёртку.

PS: у него под капотом тот же гем `unicode`. Просто доступ попроще.

---

*См. также: [Как сделать каждое слово в кириллической строке с заглавной буквы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443305/181100)*

Comment: Без изменений. Такая же ошибка...

Comment: @ZEkA10000 настораживает, что он пытается преобразовать из ASCII в UTF-8. Приложите вывод `.bytes` этой строки.

Comment: Я сделал малую правку в вопросе. А точнее пояснение.

Comment: @ZEkA10000 и, скорее всего, неправильное. Хотя версия Ruby полезна.

Comment: Как раз правильное. 
При неправильном пишет: `no such file to load -- 'файл_запрашиваемый_с_помощью_require'`

Comment: @ZEkA10000 вы это в `irb` делаете, или код в файле? Если в файле, какая у него кодировка?

Comment: В файле написано UTF-8 (Без ВОМ)

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport -- недоразумение в мире Ruby, попавшее в него из-за вакханалии в Rails.
Для конвертации кириллицы в downcase на данный момент лучше всего использовать [библиотеку от Твиттера](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb):

```
require "twitter_cldr"

"Привет".localize.casefold.to_s
# => "привет"
```

Answer (score -1):

Наверху напишите: `#coding: utf-8` или `#coding: cp866`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: привыаю, я исправлюсь, этот ответ на самом деле короткий, фишка на баг